# Loading wifi drivers on a Lenovo laptop debian 8

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, iwlwifi

I downloaded the firmware and copied it to /lib/firmware and still I keep getting errors.

Contents of /lib/firmware :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  337520 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  337572 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  689680 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  701228 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  695876 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  707392 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  670484 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  667284 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  666792 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1180356 Jul 15 12:13 iwlwifi-3165-15.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  150100 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  187972 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  353240 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  340696 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  337400 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  454608 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  444128 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  677296 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  679436 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  463692 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  469780 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  683236 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  679780 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  679380 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  885224 Jun 18  2015 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1180224 Jul 15 15:46 iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1180356 Jul 15 12:13 iwlwifi-7265-15.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  690452 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  691960 Jun 16  2014 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1008692 Jun 18  2015 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1384256 Jul 15 15:46 iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode
```

Dmesg output:

```
[    8.549314] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode (-2)
[    8.549420] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.549447] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode (-2)
[    8.549546] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.549569] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode (-2)
[    8.549667] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.549689] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode (-2)
[    8.549786] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.549807] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode (-2)
[    8.549905] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.549925] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode (-2)
[    8.550093] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.550114] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode (-2)
[    8.550280] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.550301] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode (-2)
[    8.550467] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.550488] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode (-2)
[    8.550654] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.550674] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode (-2)
[    8.550839] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L, what is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` (to identify your wifi card)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing firmware:

```
root@server:~# apt-get install -t jessie-backports firmware-iwlwifi
```